Android Talkback changing contentDescription and action for dropdown view element?
I have a dropdown represented by an ExposedDropdownMenu style on a TextInputLayout view element.
<TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    ...>
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="textview_dropdown"
        ...
     />
</TextInputLayout>

I have an arrayadapter set to this autoCompleteTextView using a simple dropdown xml linear
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dropdown_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

Finally I have the array adapter set to the dropdown textview in a fragment:
val dropdownListAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item, R.id.dropdown_textview, listOfElements)
                _binding?.textview_dropdown?.setAdapter(dropdownListAdapter)

Right now, with default Talkbalk verbosity, it just reads the text followed by an action for a Button ("Double Tap to activate"). Is there a way to create an AccessibilityDelegate and set it to this dropdown element so I can change its content description and the action to say "Double Tap to Select" instead of "Activate"?
Code that I have tried while the textview_dropdown element was focused and expanded; this didn't work:
 val dropdownLinearLayout : LinearLayout? = view.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_linearlayout)
                dropdownLinearLayout?.let {
                    ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(
                        dropdownLinearLayout,
                        object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
                            override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
                                host: View,
                                info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
                            ) {
                                super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                                info.addAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_SELECT)
                                info.removeAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_CLICK)
                            }
                        })
                }
                val dropdownTextView : TextView? = view.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_textview)
                dropdownTextView?.let {
                    ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(
                        dropdownTextView,
                        object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
                            override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
                                host: View,
                                info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
                            ) {
                                super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                                info.addAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_SELECT)
                                info.removeAction(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_CLICK)
                            }
                        })
                }

Edit: I want to append with a different question but similar topic. How can I overwrite the autocompletetextview with a custom accessibilityDelegate as well? Any attempt to override onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo results in breaking the dropdown functionality along with not reading out the text field properly.
Any tips in the right direction would be appreciated.
